# Storing JSON objects in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, json, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, mysql-workbench

I want to stroe json objects in mysql table as one column. How can i achieve this task from mysql workbench ? And how can i parse/retrieve the json from the table ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: Why is this question tagged MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server? Are you working with all of them or just MySQL? Why are you storing data that you then need to parse? Why not just parse the data before storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store any big size data in BLOB columns.

You can retrieve the data as anything like normal query.

Comment: @ MGPJ How can i parse the field/object which i am getting from json_table ? If i have Json object is the following {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}